# Twig number format without rounding decimals

Tags: twig, number-formatting

How is it possible in twig to format a number, without rounding off the decimals? 
For example, if the user inputs

12345.35, output should be 12,345.35

12345.356, output should be  12,345.356

12345.3567, output should be  12,345.3567

I tried number_format filter but the first parameter is precision to which the decimals should be rounded to. If I use `12345.35|number_format(4, '.', ',')` the result is  12,345.3500 which is not the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should determine the number of decimals you have in the number before formatting it. Not quite obvious but I don't find another solution.

Try with this macro:

```
{% macro show_number(n) %}
  {%- spaceless %}
    {% set decimals = n | split('.')[1] | default('') | length %}
    {{ n | number_format(decimals, '.', ',') }}
  {% endspaceless -%}
{% endmacro %}
```

Runnable example [here](http://twigfiddle.com/xzvg90)

Comment: Thats brilliant. Works well. +1 for the demo.